# Selenium Firefox 56 webdriver via geckodriver results in error: Can not connect to the Service

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, geckodriver

I am using geckodriver for Firefox and I'm running Python 3 with Selenium. This is my code in the file `script.py`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
```

Once I run it with `python3 script.py` with my terminal, it launches Firefox but simply doesn't load the page, nor does it insert the link in the address bar. My geckodriver is installed at this location: `/usr/local/bin/geckodriver`.

After waiting for about a minute, I get the following error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "script.py", line 3, in <module>
>     browser = webdriver.Firefox()
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
>     keep_alive=True)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 151, in __init__
>     self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 240, in start_session
>     response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 308, in execute
>     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
>     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused
> ```

I already searched a lot for fixes but none of them worked.

After I realized, I was using Firefox ESR instead of the normal one, I switched to the normal Firefox version and faced this problem:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "script.py", line 3, in <module>
>     driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'/root/Downloads/firefox-56.0.1/firefox/firefox')
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 144, in __init__
>     self.service.start()
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 102, in start
>     raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path)
> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service /root/Downloads/firefox-56.0.1/firefox/firefox
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Selenium/Geckodriver/Browser are you using?

Anyway, do you set the `executable_path`:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'pathTo/geckodriver')
```

?

**EDIT**

If you are using:

- Selenium version = 3.6.0
- Geckodriver version = 0.19.0
- Firefox version = 52.4.0

Your problem is Firefox. From [GeckoDriver releases](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases), is recommended **Firefox 55.0 (and greater)**.

Comment: Nope still getting the same problem. Selenium version = 3.6.0, Geckodriver version = 0.19.0, Firefox version = 52.4.0

Comment: Realised i was using Firefox ESR instead of normal Firefox, switched to normal Firefox and im still facing the same problem. edited orginal post with new error.